# How to fix SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I get the SyntaxError: 'return' outside function - when i run the lines of code as i try to complete my first Tensorflow model

```
 predictions = {
        "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
        "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
    }
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
      return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)
```

Tried different indentations

```
predictions = {
    "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
    "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
}
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)
```

Comment: is the entire code inside a function ?

Comment: Please include the full code, its not clear what is the problem from the snippet you are showing.